# Как найти все элементы с определенным контентом и удалить их со страницы JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно через консоль браузера, найти все элементы со значением 24 и удалить их со страницы.

```
<div id="shows" class="shows">
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">21</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">13</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
</div>
```

То есть удалить 2 блока

```
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
    <div class="show">
        <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
        <a href="/show/xxx">                    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
$(".show").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("span").html() === "24") {
    $(this).remove()
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shows" class="shows">
  <div class="show">
    <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
    <a href="/show/xxx">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <span class="label label-dark ec">24</span>
    <a href="/show/xxx">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <span class="label label-dark ec">21</span>
    <a href="/show/xxx">
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <span class="label label-dark ec">13</span>
    <a href="/show/xxx">
  </div>
</div>
```

Имейте ввиду что проверка содержимого каждой ноды крайне ресурсозатратное мероприятие, поэтому такой вариант стоит использовать только в крайних случаях.

Тоже самое на JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".show").forEach(item => {
  if (item.querySelector("span").innerHTML === "24") {
    item.remove()
  }
})
```

здесь метод для перебора называется [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).